# simple java dialog to choose option

Tags: java, user-interface

I am looking for a one-liner that spawns a window and allows me to pick (graphically, e.g. using a combobox) one of several options.

I can create a MessageBox with the following code, but that does not allow interaction:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "read this", "title", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

The dialog should look (somewhat) like this tk widget: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLk9j.png

and offer a signature like

```
// return null or the index in the array
Integer letUserChooseIndex(String[] options)
```

but might also accept a `Collection<Object>` or something similar.

What is the simplest option here?

Comment: *"What is the simplest option here?"* It is called: [research](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) has the functionality to have a combobox built in. This is from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JOptionPaneshowInputDialogComponentpObjectmStringtintmIconiObjectoObjecti.htm):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JOptionPane Sample");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button = new JButton("Ask");
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Component source = (Component) actionEvent.getSource();
        Object response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(source,
            "Choose One?", "JOptionPane Sample",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] { "A", "B", "C" },
            "B");
        System.out.println("Response: " + response);
      }
    };
    button.addActionListener(actionListener);
    f.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The above code uses the following method:

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                     Object message,
                     String title,
                     int messageType,
                     Icon icon,
                     Object[] selectionValues,
                     Object initialSelectionValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, the specific `showInputDialog` overload you mention is what I was looking for.